# getting values from another page

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

In my app i have two Activities OpenAccount and BillAccount. On the Button Click in OpenAccount we are navigating to BillAccount. From BillAccount acticity again we are going back into previous Activity OpenAccount. Here while navigating back i want some variable values in OpenAccount. 
I tried by

```
intent.putExtra("trnxnId", trnxnId)
```

and to get values in OpenAccount

```
intent.getExtras().getString("trnxnId");
```

but it giver error on first load of OpenAccount since that time it doesnt have value of this variable with intent.

Please help how can we get values in this case?

Comment: [BillAccount Activity-- intent.putExtra("trnxnId", trnxnId);] & [OpenAcount Activity -- Intent.getExtras().getString("trnxnId");], but on load of OpenAccount, it do not finds the value of "trnxnId", here it gives error.

Comment: can u plz post your full code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("trnxnID",trnxnID);
it.putExtras(bundle);
```

And you can get it by:

```
it.getExtras().getString("trnxnID");
```

Comment: thanks sunil, I tried using this but the activity OpenAccount itself coming from an Intent action, here in first activity OpenAccount still on getIntent it is throwing NullPointerExcepetion.

Answer (score 0):

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("trnxnId").equals(null) ? "" : getIntent().getStringExtra("trnxnId");
```

try using above, it handles the case when no value is returned.

Comment: thanks tushar, I tried using this but the activity OpenAccount itself coming from an Intent action, here in first activity OpenAccount  still on getIntent it is throwing NullPointerExcepetion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using startActivityForResult if you are not doing that already.

In OpenAccount activity:

Where you start the BillAccount from OpenAccount:

```
int requestCode = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BillAccount.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Implement this method in OpenAccount:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    data.getStringExtra("trnxnId");
  }
}
```

In BillAccount before you finish it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("trnxnID", trnxnID);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```